# Prevent page leaving and capture Leave button Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to prevent a user from leaving a page before clicking on submit button.And when he confirm leave i want to execute something (delayed leave).

i use this function

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
                var myPageIsDirty = "d";  
                if (myPageIsDirty) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.returnValue = '';
                }

            });
```

This surely warns the user. But my requirement to handle the leave button click event and do something

Answer (score 0):

leave button confirmation can be done by:

```
<a href="" onclick="return confirm('do you want to leave?');">Submit</a>
```

Comment: i think you didnt get my requirement

Comment: this is not my requirement